# How to get formatted date

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    from_date = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
    to_date = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
```

This shows me form with jquery calendar. I use i18n and l10n and date in post looks like this:

```
12.02.2014
```

But I want to use this dates in filter (date_*lte, date*_gte) - 2014-02-12

How to do this?

Comment: Try to use [input_formats property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats) for `DateField`

Comment: Yes, it works but only take me invalidate. I want to AdminDateWidget  insert the correct date - now it insert date with dots (locales). widgets.AdminDateWidget(format(...)) not working.